# Update a table with WHERE time BETWEEN times and COUNT(column)>1

Tags: mysql

I'm having trouble with this one MySQL query -

```
UPDATE users

SET field = 1

WHERE time BETWEEN '_time1_' and '_time2_'

AND count(email) > 1;
```

It says I have an error using a group-by function at count().  I've tried HAVING COUNT also.  I'm not sure how to specify this query, the actual answer might be more nested than I figured.

count(column) seems to work with SELECT but not with UPDATE.

Comment: `COUNT()` is actually a group function, it returns the numbers of lines that were grouped by the specified columns. You'll need to run a subquery to group user records by a common column value before running this update.

Comment: Show us an example of your users records. Do you have more than one record per user? How could you group them?

Comment: I'm trying to mark all records that have an email that occurs more than once between a time frame

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you want to update records with more than one occurrence within `time1` and `time2`, this should do the trick:

```
UPDATE users
SET field = 1
WHERE
  time BETWEEN '_time1_' AND '_time2_'
  AND (
    SELECT COUNT(email)
    FROM users AS ucount
    WHERE ucount.time BETWEEN '_time1_' AND '_time2_'
      AND users.email = ucount.email
    GROUP BY ucount.email
  ) > 1
```

But **REMEMBER**: always back up your data before performing risky bulk updates or do it within a transaction and make sure you got that right before committing.

You can also check what you'll update by doing so:

```
SELECT * -- Just replace 'UPDATE' for 'SELECT * FROM'
FROM users
-- SET field = 1 -- And comment 'SET' to perform the SELECT
WHERE
  time BETWEEN '_time1_' AND '_time2_'
  AND (
    SELECT COUNT(email)
    FROM users AS ucount
    WHERE ucount.time BETWEEN '_time1_' AND '_time2_'
      AND users.email = ucount.email
    GROUP BY ucount.email
  ) > 1
```

The above query will return you all the records that will be updated if you run the `UPDATE` query.

Comment: second SET needed to be commented because select

Comment: oops! That went by unnoticed. Already fixed, thanks for pointing it out @Kiwizoom !